# Arguments Against Quantifier Neutralism?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, ontology, philosophy-of-language

Are there any good arguments for rejecting quantifier neutrality advocated in Azzouni’s “Ontology Without Borders”?

Comment: Not many, critics usually take issue with Azzouni's underlying brand of nominalism rather that with quantifier neutralism that is just a pragmatic formal device that services it. Belleri offers some in her [review of his book](https://www.philinq.it/index.php/philinq/article/download/402/261/1297):"*The possibility of such a verbal dispute seems to defeat the advertised benefits of quantifier neutrality. After all, quantifier onticity, namely the doctrine that relates quantification to ontological commitment, ties existence to a formal device, which arguably has a univocal semantics.*"

Comment: Azzouni's PFL quantifier neutrality and FPL derelativization essentially as monads mainly invite criticism to provide a satisfactory account for truth-making and grounding in addition to its obvious disalignment with pragmatic linguistic convention of natural languages and scientific practices, easily leading to ontological eliminativism and deflationism, not unlike Glick's OSR. Mathematically it's equivalent to existing foundation and just like the categorical 2nd order arithmetic, its underlying FPL absorbs the inevitable incompleteness...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thank you (and everyone else!) for the responses. I have one other question regarding a problem with this book: the “features” themselves that remain in Azzouni’s ontology seem to just behave as informational properties of the world. Is he really eliminating properties if he replaces them with a functional equivalent?

Comment: He suggests that what we call 'properties' are just linguistic conveniences or placeholders for patterns that we observe in the world, not necessarily providing a functionalist theory of properties. Instead, he is proposing a deflationary eliminative view, suggesting that the talk of properties can be replaced by more primitive or nominalistic expressions without losing any explanatory or descriptive power. The features that remain in his ontology are more like tools for conveying information about the phenomenal world rather than (abstract) entities/functions with independent existence...

Answer (score 2):

Azzouni's thesis is that accepting the truth of a quantified expression does not automatically commit oneself to the existence of the things quantified over.

Yet, I could only really believe that all my eggs are rotten if I also really believed that those eggs really exist to begin with.

Also--to answer a comment here on the possible incidence of the deflationary theory of truth--I cannot possibly really believe that it is not true that all my eggs are rotten if I really believe that all my eggs are rotten.

Comment: Doesn’t Azzouni argue that accepting deflationary truth avoids this problem?

Comment: @GhostRocket "*deflationary truth*" See my edit. 2. "*avoids this problem*" What do you mean? That it is somehow not true that I believe that all my eggs are rotten when I believe that all my eggs are rotten?

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Azzouni's position is that quantifiers in natural language are not fundamentally ambiguous, hence neutral. It stands in distinction to the position that quantifiers differ between a domain reading and an inferential reading.

The latter position is advocated, for example, by Hofweber who bases his claim on the fact that we can successfully speak of things that do not exist and we can draw inferences from such thoughts, even though non-existent things lie outside the domain of quantification. He also offers an argument based on the claim that we can quantify over facts and propositions, but when we do so, truth values are not preserved within 'that clauses', e.g. "X fears that p". He claims that if the quantification were referential, i.e. referring to a thing within a domain, we would expect truth values to be preserved, so this is evidence of a separate, inferential reading of the quantifier.

Speaking for myself, I don't agree with Hofweber's reasoning at all, so it is possible I am failing to do justice to it. You can read his account in his paper, "Idealism and the Harmony of Thought and Reality", Mind, Vol. 128, 699–734, (2019).

There are other respects in which philosphers of language have questioned whether quantifiers may be distinguished in some way, but these are mostly concerned with quantifiers in formal logic rather than quantifiers in natural language. For example, David Chalmers speaks of a distinction between lightweight and heavyeight quantification, and Kit Fine speaks of a thick/thin distinction. (David Chalmers, "Ontological anti-realism". In D. Chalmers, D. Manley, & R. Wasserman (Eds.), Metametaphysics: New essays on the foundations of ontology (2009). pp. 77–129. Kit Fine, "The question of ontology", op. cit., pp. 157–177.)

Comment: Quantification also raises questions of [transworld identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-transworld/) in the context of modal logic (the sort of logic you have to use if you want to formalize hypotheticals and counterfactuals, which appears to be what you describe Hofweber as talking about).